# How to set discounts on upsell/crosssell products in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cross-sells, up-sells, upselling

I want to set Discount on a Product which is Up-sell/cross-sell for other product.

Example: 
I am selling the following in my Magento store

- Blazer $100,
- Shirt $60 and
- Pant $80

`Blazer` is a up-sell product for `shirt` When customer buys `Shirt` for **$80**, `Blazer` will show-up as up-sell product, and that should give **30% discount** of `Blazer` actual price.

But if the same customer Buys the `Blazer` directly then cost should be **$100 (not discounted price)**

How can I achieve this? Is there something already inbuilt in Magento or can I make this work with little code change or is there any extension that is available?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to give discount for "Product" which is display **under** "up sell" section. but not to give discount for **Same** Product which is displaying **directly** in product view page. For my knowledge, This is **not Possible**....

there is a **bad** alternative solution is to create **same Product 2 times**. Assign 1st Product to `upsell` and give discount for that product and display 2nd product in product view page [ without discount ]

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question properly, I Modified the question  with an example, Can you please look into the question

Comment: @KiranPadma updated the answer......

Comment: Though it 's not a bad idea, I will try your idea.